# Vim list all search results

Tags: vim, search

Is there a way to list all search results of vim in a separate buffer, sort of like what Ctrl-] does when multiple matches are found? Although browsing with n and N is okay too, I believe it might be even faster that way.

Answer (score 4):

[`:grep`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:grep) will use the [QuickFix window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html), which will let you see all the matches and quickly jump between them.  For example, `:grep <cword> %` will search for the token currently under the cursor, within the current file.

Comment: `:grep` invokes external `grep` command so you can use desired `grep` arguments to expand your search, e.g. `:grep -A4 -B2 <pattern> %`

Answer (score 1):

from [tuxdiary.com](http://tuxdiary.com/2015/02/15/vim-list-all-matching-lines/)

### vimgrep (Error List)

```txt
:vimgrep pattern %
:copen
```

Use <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> keys to navigate the list, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select a match.
Traverse the matches in the open file using <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd> the regular way.

### lvim (Location List)

```txt
:lvim pattern %
:lopen
```

Navigation is similar to that in vimgrep.

### global search

```txt
:g/regular-expression/p
```

Note that grep got its name from this command sequence!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this one, but I've had it bookmarked for a while and it may be fairly close to what you want:

```
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2255
```

Since it ties into the quickfix system, you can show the matches in the quickfix window; see "`:help quickfix-window`".